# Syntax errors in RPGLE program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am creating a RPG program (In PUB400 server) that simulates an ATM cashier with some options. This RPG program uses three tables as: Customers(Id, Name, RegistrationDate), Accounts(AccountNumber, CustomerId, Balance) and Transactions(Id, CustomerId, TransactionType, TransactionDate).

When I am coding the RPG program I get multiple sintax errors that I do not know how to fix. For example, in

```
0001.00 D Withdrawal      pr                                                 
0001.01 D CustomerId                          Like(Accounts.CustomerId)      
0001.02 D AccountNumber                       Like(Accounts.AccountNumber)   
0004.00 D Amount                              Like(Accounts.Balance)         
0005.00                                                                      
0006.00 D Withdrawal      PI                                                 
0007.00 D CustomerId                          Like(Accounts.CustomerId)      
0008.00 D AccountNumber                       Like(Accounts.AccountNumber)   
0009.00 D Amount                              Like(Accounts.Balance)         
0010.00                                                                      
0011.00  /FREE                                                               
0012.00 //Check if the account has sufficient balance                        
0013.00   SELECT Balance INTO :Balance                                       
0014.00   FROM Accounts                                                      
0015.00   WHERE CustomerId = :CustomerId                                     
0016.00   AND AccountNumber = :AccountNumber                                
0017.00   FOR UPDATE OF Accounts;                                               
0018.00  IF :Balance >= :Amount;                                                
0019.00 //Update the balance                                                    
0020.00  UPDATE Accounts                                                        
0021.00  SET Balance = Balance - :Amount                                        
0022.00  WHERE CustomerId = :CustomerId                                         
0023.00  AND AccountNUmber = :AccountNumber;                                    
0024.00 //Record the transaction                                                
0025.00  INSERT INTO Transactions(CustomerId, TransactionType, TransactionDate) 
0026.00  VALUES (: CustomerId, 'W', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);                        
0027.00  ELSE;                                                                 
0028.00 //Display an error message                                             
0029.00  ENDIF;                                                                
0030.00 /END-FREE                                                              
        ****************** End of data ****************************************
```

This is the return displayed of the WRKSPLF:

```
5770WDS V7R5M0  220415 RN        IBM ILE RPG             REUY851/ATMSIM1      
Command  . . . . . . . . . . . . :   CRTBNDRPG                               
Issued by  . . . . . . . . . . :     REUY85                                
Program  . . . . . . . . . . . . :   ATMSIM1                                 
Library  . . . . . . . . . . . :     REUY851                               
Text 'description' . . . . . . . :   *SRCMBRTXT                              
Source Member  . . . . . . . . . :   ATMSIM1                                 
Source File  . . . . . . . . . . :   QRPGLESRC                               
Library  . . . . . . . . . . . :     REUY851                               
CCSID  . . . . . . . . . . . . :     273                                   
Text 'description' . . . . . . . :   RGP PROGRAM ATM TRANSACTIONS            
Last Change  . . . . . . . . . . :   04/20/23  15:45:05                      
Generation severity level  . . . :   10                                      
Default activation group . . . . :   *YES                                    
Compiler options . . . . . . . . :   *XREF      *GEN       *NOSECLVL  *SHOWC 
                                     *EXPDDS    *EXT       *NOSHOWSKP *NOSRC 
                                     *DEBUGIO   *UNREF     *NOEVENTF
Debugging views  . . . . . . . . :   *STMT                          
Debug encryption key . . . . . . :   *NONE                          
Output . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *PRINT                         
Optimization level . . . . . . . :   *NONE                          
Source listing indentation . . . :   *NONE                          
Type conversion options  . . . . :   *NONE                          
Sort sequence  . . . . . . . . . :   *HEX                           
Language identifier  . . . . . . :   *JOBRUN                        
Replace program  . . . . . . . . :   *NO                            
User profile . . . . . . . . . . :   *USER                          
Authority  . . . . . . . . . . . :   *LIBCRTAUT                     
Truncate numeric . . . . . . . . :   *YES                           
Fix numeric  . . . . . . . . . . :   *NONE                          
Target release . . . . . . . . . :   *CURRENT                       
Allow null values  . . . . . . . :   *NO                            
Define condition names . . . . . :   *NONE                                  
Enable performance collection  . :   *PEP                                   
Profiling data . . . . . . . . . :   *NOCOL                                 
Licensed Internal Code options . :                                          
Generate program interface . . . :   *NO                                    
Include directory  . . . . . . . :                                          
Preprocessor options . . . . . . :   *NONE                                  
REQUIRE PROTOTYPE FOR EXPORT . . :   *NO                                    
                                                  -=* http://pub400.com *=-  
5770WDS V7R5M0  220415 RN        IBM ILE RPG             REUY851/ATMSIM1     
Line   <---------------------- Source Specifications -------------------------
Number ....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+.
                          S o u r c e   L i s t i n g                         
    1 D Withdrawal      PR                                                   
======>  aaaaaaaaaa                                                           
*RNF3788 30 a      000100  DFTACTGRP(*NO) must be specified for a prototype th
                        not have the EXTPGM keyword.                      
    2 D CustomerId                          Like(Accounts.CustomerId)       
    3 D AccountNumber                       Like(Accounts.AccountNumber)    
    4 D Amount                              Like(Accounts.Balance)          
    5                                                                       
    6 D Withdrawal      PI                                                  
======>  aaaaaaaaaa                                                          
*RNF3751 30 a      000600  External procedure on prototype for main procedure
                        same as actual external name.                     
    7 D CustomerId                          Like(Accounts.CustomerId)       
    8 D AccountNumber                       Like(Accounts.AccountNumber)    
    9 D Amount                              Like(Accounts.Balance)          
    10                                                                       
    11  /FREE                                                                
    12 //Check if the account has sufficient balance                         
======> aaaaaa                                                               
*RNF0274 30 a      001200  Compiler directive not recognized; directive ignore 
    13   SELECT Balance INTO :Balance                                          
======>         aaaaaaa                                                        
*RNF5507 30 a      001300  A semi-colon is not specified at the end of a free- 
                           statement.                                          
    14   FROM Accounts                                                         
    15   WHERE CustomerId = :CustomerId                                        
    16   AND AccountNumber = :AccountNumber                                    
    17   FOR UPDATE OF Accounts;                                               
    18  IF :Balance >= :Amount;                                                
======>a                                                                       
*RNF0257 30 a      001800  Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out 
                           sequence.                                           
    19 //Update the balance                                                    
======> aaaaaaa                                                                
*RNF0274 30 a      001900  Compiler directive not recognized; directive ignore 
    20  UPDATE Accounts                                                        
======>a                                                                       
*RNF0257 30 a      002000  Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out 
                           sequence.                                           
    21  SET Balance = Balance - :Amount                                        
======>a                                                                       
*RNF0257 30 a      002100  Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out 
                           sequence.                                           
    22  WHERE CustomerId = :CustomerId                                         
======>a                                                                       
*RNF0257 30 a      002200  Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out 
                           sequence.                                           
    23  AND AccountNUmber = :AccountNumber;                                    
======>a                                                                       
*RNF0257 30 a      002300  Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out
                        sequence.                                          
    24 //Record the transaction                                               
======> aaaaaaa                                                               
*RNF0274 30 a      002400  Compiler directive not recognized; directive ignore
    25  INSERT INTO Transactions(CustomerId, TransactionType, TransactionDate)
======>a                                                                      
*RNF0257 30 a      002500  Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out
                           sequence.                                          
    26  VALUES (: CustomerId, 'W', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);                        
======>a                                                                      
*RNF0257 30 a      002600  Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out
                           sequence.                                          
    27  ELSE;                                                                 
======>a                                                                       
*RNF0257 30 a      002700  Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out 
                           sequence.                                           
    28 //Display an error message                                              
======> aaaaaaaa                                                               
*RNF0274 30 a      002800  Compiler directive not recognized; directive ignore 
    29  ENDIF;                                                                 
======>a                                                                       
*RNF0257 30 a      002900  Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out 
                           sequence.                                           
    30 /END-FREE                                                               
======>a                                                                       
*RNF0257 30 a      003000  Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out 
                           sequence.                                           
*RNF5177 30     13 001300  ENDyy operation missing for SELECT operation group  
                           statement 13; END assumed.
```

Comment: It is hard to find any programmers who understand RPG language nowadays

Comment: No it's not, I know many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, you are on v7.5, you should not be using any fixed format at all. Start your programs with `**free` starting in line 1, column 1 of your source. In this case there is NO special columns in the code, no comment area, no specification column, no sequence columns. All your code can start in column 1 of the source line. As Dam said, SQL statements start with `exec sql`, variables in the SQL statement must be prefixed by a colon (:), but that only applies to variables embedded in SQL statements.

Also drop `/free` and `/end-free` statements, they just clutter the code.

It seems you need to find a better you-tube channel to learn RPG coding from. The one you are currently using is confusing you with obsolete techniques.

One thing you are missing is your control specs. These were H specs in days past, but now in the `**free` world, they are `ctl-opt`

The set of control options I use depends on whether I am coding a program or a module. for Programs I use:

```
ctl-opt DatFmt(*iso) TimFmt(*iso)
        DftActGrp(*No) ActGrp(*New)
        BndDir('COMMON') 
        Option(*NoDebugIo: *SrcStmt: *NoUnref)
        Main();
```

The parameter for Main() is the name of the main procedure. I always use the program name for this, it is also the source file name.

For modules I use:

```
ctl-opt DatFmt(*iso) TimFmt(*iso)
        Option(*NoDebugIo: *SrcStmt: *NoUnref)
        NoMain;
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there are a numerous problems, here are a few points:

- Before SQL statements in RPGLE you have to use:

> Exec SQL

- RPG variables in SQL must be prefixed by : like you have done, but not in rpg statements, in your "IF" line 18 there is no need of :
- You are in V7R5 so there is no need to use /FREE and END-FREE
- At the top before PR declaration you must use a H declaration